# Why is .onDelete not working for macOS app?

Tags: swiftui

I have noticed .onDelete is not working for macOS apps. I noticed this first when looking at the Core Data sample code Xcode provided for a macOS app. Then when I tried to implement .onDelete for my project it still did not work. I do not understand why.

I have tried different things but have found no solution to make onDelete work. Here is my current code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var notes = Notes()
    @State private var AddNote = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(notes.newNotes) { note in
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "folder")
                    
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(note.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                        }

                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeNote)
               
            }
            
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    showingAddExpense = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $AddNote) {
                AddView(notes: notes)
            }
        }
    }

    func removeNote(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        notes.newNotes.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to share your `Notes()` implementation ??

Comment: `.onDelete` does work fine on macOS. But there is just no EditButton or editMode on Mac, so you only have swipeAction on MousePad to activate it, which is not very intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, use `.onDeleteCommand` to remove list items.

You also have to keep track of the selected item in the list because Mac lists don't have an Edit button like iOS does.

The following question has multiple approaches for deleting list items on Mac:

[SwiftUI on macOS: How to enable UI for onDelete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59765271/swiftui-on-macos-how-to-enable-ui-for-ondelete-deletion-from-list)

The following article explain how to remove items from SwiftUI lists on Mac:

[Removing Items from SwiftUI Lists in Mac Apps](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/removing-items-from-swiftui-lists-in-mac-apps/)

Answer (score -1):

Select your item in the list.

Then click "Edit/Delete"